# Trouble Passing array of Structs using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, struct, arguments

I'm having problems with a function that I use to write to an element of an array.

I think it might be because I'm not passing the array of struct correctly. I was wondering if someone can point out how to do this correctly. I've been screwing it up more than fixing it.

let's say I have a function `menu.c`
I declare my struct `newPerson person[MAX_PERSONS];`
I then run my function `addPerson(person, &num);`
which is the following

```
void addPerson(newPerson *pers, int *num){
    pers[*num] = (newPerson) {
                    "Michelle", "Leo", "6136458798", STUDENT,
                    .data = {.s = {9, 1234.50, 3}}
                };
    *num = *num + 1;
}
```

It runs, but won't print out correctly, I'm guessing because it doesn't write where I want it to `pers[num]`. I tried calling the function this way also `addPerson(&person, &num);` instead of just `addPerson(person, &num);` but then I receive this error

> warning: passing argument 1 of ‘addPerson’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

and

> note: expected ‘struct newPerson *’ but argument is of type ‘struct newPerson (*)[20]’

I've tried changing the function to `void addPerson(newPerson *pers[], int *num){` as well but nothing there. Was wondering if anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong here and how I can fix my problem. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Forgot to mention that the addPerson function works in some places where I run it.

```
int menu(int num) {
    newPerson person[MAX_PERSONS];
    //printf("THE NUMBER START OF MENU IS %d\n", num); test counter

    //addPerson(person, &num);    <- WRITES AND READS PROPERLY IF DONE HERE

    int option;
    printf(
            "\n\tPlease choose one of the following options to continue (0-9): ");
    scanf("%d", &option);


if (option == 1) { //program will ask for name input
    addPerson(person, &num);  <- HOWEVER IT DOES NOT WRITE OR READ PROPERLY HERE
    menu(num);
}
```

Both functions are called in `menu.c`
However when I call addPerson in the if statement, it does not write/read properly.

Just solved the problem by declaring the struct as static!
`static newPerson person[MAX_PERSONS];`

I'm not sure if this is taboo or anything, but it fixed my problem!

Comment: I'm going to make a wild guess that you are accessing `person` out of bounds. What's the value of `num` before you use in `addPerson`?

Comment: The problem is that the `person` array is a local variable, and you're calling the `menu` function recursively.

Answer (score 1):

> By making static you have made the code inefficient as the memory for
>   the data structure has been set aside regardless of whether it is
>   needed or not while the program is executing.(With a static data
>   structure, the size of the structure is fixed.)

Declare the function like

```
void addPerson(newPerson *pers[],int *num)
```

call the function like

```
void addPerson(newPerson *pers, int *num);
```

OR

```
void addPerson(newPerson pers[], int *num);
```

Comment: Declare the function like void addPerson(newPerson *pers[],int *num)

call the function like void addPerson(newPerson *pers, int *num); OR void addPerson(newPerson pers[], int *num);

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by declaring the struct as static

`static newPerson person[MAX_PERSONS];`

Not sure if this is an actual fix or if it's just masking my problem though.

Comment: What is value of `MAX_PERSONS`?Do you have sufficient stack space?

Comment: That's one way to fix the problem that the `person` array is a local variable. However, you still have a recursion problem. If the `menu` function calls itself, the stack will grow until there's a stack overflow and the program crashes. Without seeing more of the program, it's hard to advise how to fix the problem. Posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would make this question much easier to answer.